# ASP.NET Live Website Replication Ideas

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis-8

I have a Dedicated Windows Server 2012 lets call it 'A' where my ASP.NET 4.5 website is up and active on IIS 8. Due to the many downtime issues, I want to now move my website to Azure.

I created an Azure VM with an identical environment and copied all files and database. However I am unable to get the website up and running (2 days now) on the VM.

Is there a way using which I can replicate the exact environment that I had in Server 'A'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy your existing VM (if it is in VHD format) to Azure.  See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-createupload-vhd/ for more information.

If your server is a physical, you can use something like https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42497 to do a conversion, and then upload that to Azure.

Lastly, using services such as [chef](https://github.com/chef/chef), [puppet](https://puppet.com/), or [DSC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/overview) to ensure that server configurations are standard across machines.

Comment: Thanks @CtrlDot. I am pretty sure it is a VM but I do not have access to the VHD (probably due to Windows Server license issue). In this case what do I do? Treat it as physical?

Comment: I think those tools should work on virtual.  I'm curious what the original problem you are having is.